# How to change Apache thrift Frame size

Tags: java, thrift

I am getting following exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Frame size (1937007972) larger than max length (16384000)!
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:137) ~[libthrift-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101) ~[libthrift-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86) ~[libthrift-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readStringBody(TBinaryProtocol.java:380) ~[libthrift-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:230) ~[libthrift-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69) ~[libthrift-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
```

Is there a way to change the size to unlimited, as I am not sure what will be my data size.

Comment: "*Is there a way to change the size to unlimited*"  -  the whole idea behind `TFramedTransport` is to **limit** the size of the message. So what you want is just a contradiction. If you don't want a limit, don't use `TFramedTransport`. If you are after the buffering effect, use `TBufferedTransport` instead. FInally, if you're at the client end, you have to live with what the server end expects (`TFramedTransport`) and allows (the size limit).

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is a specific CTOR for Java which can be passed the frame size for both [the server side](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/transport/TFramedTransport.java#L57) and the [client side](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/transport/TFramedTransport.java#L70).

Client CTOR

```
/** 
* Constructor wraps around another transport 
*/ 
public TFramedTransport(TTransport transport, int maxLength) { 
   transport_ = transport; 
   maxLength_ = maxLength; 
 }
```

Server side factory including the CTOR

```
public static class Factory extends TTransportFactory { 
  private int maxLength_; 

  public Factory() { 
    maxLength_ = TFramedTransport.DEFAULT_MAX_LENGTH; 
  } 

  public Factory(int maxLength) { 
    maxLength_ = maxLength; 
  } 

  @Override 
  public TTransport getTransport(TTransport base) { 
     return new TFramedTransport(base, maxLength_); 
  } 
}
```

So the solution is to specify it when constructing the Thrift protocol/transport stack.